# How to deploy from Visual Studio to a IIS using custom user

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I'm trying to publish a web application to an IIS site, but it fails to authenticate. I know I'm using the correct username and password.

I can publish using the Administrator account, but not the custom user, even though it's also in the Administrator group.

I've tried to add the custom user in IIS Manager Permissions for the site in IIS without any luck.